# Tilting shapefile so it appears flat or seen on its edge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-frame

I don’t know exactly how to explain what it is I am trying to do so I will have to resort to a couple of pics. Hopefully that will explain it for me. I am trying to ‘tip’ shapefiles so that they are seen from the edge in an effort to create ‘alignment sheets’ with a simple linear reference to the actual map.

Is there anyway to accomplish this in ArcMap that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Not without a load of code. You need to project your points to your flat view line and the length of that line looks like the edge of the bounding extent of your blue line?

Comment: Strip maps are quite common, but you won't necessarily get the map you show -- instead it would be proportional to the cumulative measurements of the vertices.

Answer (score 2):

I think the steps are relatively straightforward and easy to automate using ArcPy, if the map is oriented North-South:

1. Get X coordinates of start and end nodes of the line
2. Use an arbitrary but constant Y value to create a feature class with one line from xStart,Y to xEnd,Y
3. Get X coordinates of each point and use them to create a feature class with points at those X values and the same Y value as used for the line.
4. Add a data frame to the layout with layers for the line and point feature classes created above and set its extent to the line feature class (probably with a small margin around it)
5. Make sure the flattened feature layers have the same symbology as their corresponding originals.

Comment: Thank you, this got me going in the right direction. Funny how such a simple process can be so tough to see, lol.

Comment: Sadly this only works with N+S rotation at zero. I will need to accomplish this with different rotations as well.